# jQuery: simple .css line to change background color does not work in Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

I am using the following line to conditionally change the background-color of TDs. 
This works fine in IE and Firefox but in Chrome it doesn't set any color at all.

I also tried to use rgb(255, 255, 0) instead but with the same result for Chrome, using version 33.0.1750.154 m which seems to be the latest one.

Is there a way to make this work in all three browsers ?

**My code snippet:**

```
$('.search').click(function() {
    var value = $(this).text();
    var color = $(this).css('background-color');
    if(color == 'transparent') {
        $('td')
        .css('background-color', '')
        .filter(function(){
            return $(this).text() === value;
        })
        .css('background-color', 'yellow');
//...
```

Thanks in advance, Tim.

Comment: Seems to work for me. Is there any relevant code that's missing?

Comment: Yep: http://jsfiddle.net/6yFeg/1 I bet the css sheet or html is usng `myclass`. It's case sensitive.

Comment: In your fiddle, the background is not yellow?

Comment: Oh yes it is...and I'm using Chrome

Comment: Thanks. I want to set the background to yellow but in Chrome it stays transparent.

Comment: You must have another JS error that is stopping this from working. Can you post your full code. The example you have provided is standard jQuery that will work in all browsers.

Comment: Thanks, All. I extended my code above. Could the issue be the checking for the transparent background color and maybe Chrome doesn't recognise it this way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the checking for "transparent" before setting the background-color was the issue as only IE and FF return the color this way whereas Chrome returns rgba(0, 0, 0, 0).

I changed the if line as follows which works for me - not sure if rgb would work as well:

```
//...
if( (color == 'transparent') || (color == 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)') ) {
/...
```

Answer (score 1):

if you can, check firstly if was any error was happed, you can look at console ..
if no error was find, please check the css selector when you inspect element was selected at blue color ...
if no, try to set a width, and height.. if now, try to set overflow: hidden, .. 
if still problem, try to set bg color and class in css file, if work fine, you can try to addClass like

```
.testColor{
background-color: yellow;
} 

jQuery(".myClass").addClass("testColor");
```

Good luck

Comment: Thanks. I extended my code above. Could the issue be the checking for the transparent background color and maybe Chrome doesn't recognise it this way ?